# How to request a list input from the user in Python?

Tags: python, function, slice

I have defined a function which requires 3 arguments, one of which must be a list.
One solution that I found works only when the list is made up of integers, which will not necessarily be the case (the types can vary within the same list). 
How to request a list type input from the user? e.g.: when something like [1,2,3] is inputted, it is considered as a list?

Comment: Read about [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: What's the relationship to the question?

Comment: is the question: how to request a list type input from the user?

Comment: @JohnDebs: "What's the relationship..?" With ast, the answer to you question is trivial. Try `ast.literal_eval("[1,2,'3']")` It will parse the list as a list, the integers as integers, the string as a string. Any other approach is going to be a lot more work (other than using `eval` but that has its own issues of safety...)

Answer (score 0):

**Here's one way:**

```
$ cat foo.py
import sys
input1 = sys.argv[1]
input2 = sys.argv[2]
print('Before\n-------')
print('input1:{},type_of_input1:{}'.format(input1,  type(input1)))
print('input2:{},type_of_input2:{}'.format(input2,  type(input2)))
print('After\n-------')
input1 = input1.split(' ')
print('input1:{},type_of_input1:{}'.format(input1,  type(input1)))
print('input2:{},type_of_input2:{}'.format(input2,  type(input2)))
$
```

**Execution output**

```
$ python foo.py 'foo bar' bat
Before
-------
input1:foo bar,type_of_input1:<type 'str'>
input2:bat,type_of_input2:<type 'str'>
After
-------
input1:['foo', 'bar'],type_of_input1:<type 'list'>
input2:bat,type_of_input2:<type 'str'>
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and safe and use `input` and convert the input into a list yourself:

```
import re
re.sub("[^\w]", " ", input('-->')).split()
-->This is a string of words converted into a list

output: 

['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'of', 'words', 'converted', 'into', 'a', 'list']
```

`input` is a built-in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 0):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
while True:
    s=raw_input("Enter a list: ")
    s=ast.literal_eval(s)
    if not isinstance(s, list):
        print "Nope! {} is a {}".format(s, type(s)) 
    else:
        break
print s
```

If you want the option of the user entering a tuple (by entering `1,2,3` for example) add `tuple` to `isinstance`:

```
import ast
while True:
    s=raw_input("Enter a list: ")
    s=ast.literal_eval(s)
    if not isinstance(s, (list, tuple)):
        print "Nope! {} is a {}".format(s, type(s)) 
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

If you completely trust user input, you can just use `eval()`. Assuming the user enters the string `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
x = input()    # Python 3, use raw_input for Python 2
y = eval(x)    # Dangerous, don't use with untrusted input

print(y)
# [1, 2, 3]

print(len(y))
# 3
```

**Update:**

`ast.literal_eval` is a better choice here.

```
import ast

x = input()    # Python 3, use raw_input for Python 2
y = ast.literal_eval(x)

print(y)
# [1, 2, 3]

print(len(y))
# 3
```

Comment: `eval` is a dangerous idea ... just waiting for someone to input `__import__("shutil").rmtree`

Comment: Agree, that's why I mentioned that it was dangerous in my answer. If the intent is for the script to be run interactively by the author, locally, it's no more dangerous than a shell prompt.

Comment: But why suggest `eval` instead of `ast.literal_eval` for such a case?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is clearly a better option. You're right, I can't think of a reason to use `eval` over it. I'll update the answer to make that clear. Thanks!